# How to create navigation bar back button based on previous ViewController

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiviewcontroller, uinavigationcontroller

I am in an strange condition and little bit novice too with iOS development. for sake of clarity using alphabet for ViewController(vA) and numerics for NavigationController(n1). Suppose I have a ViewController 'A' which is embedded in the navigation controller '1'. Below I am trying to show the navigation.
vB-> n1 -> vA
vB-> n2 -> vC -> vD -> vA
I have a bar button item on `vB` which redirected me to `vA`. Due to some requirement I am using present modally segue to go from `vB` to 'vA' so there isn't any back button on `vA` whereas for second condition I got the default back Button due to the `push segue`. In first condition, for navigating back, I have added a bar button item and dismissing the view on button action like below.

```
[self dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:^{ NSLog(@"controller dismissed"); }];
```

Its working fine for the first condition, but navigating by second condition, when comes on the `vA` I got my custom back button instead of the default back button, which is obvious, by clicking it I got `redirected to vB` whereas my requirement is to `go back on vD`. So how can I do this, hide custom back bar button if `coming from vD`. What I am thinking for the solution is to get the previous ViewController, and based on that create custom button. But I am not sure, is this a right approach. Please guide me if there is any other simple approach to do this.

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
if(viewController isEqualTo @" vB")
{
 //create custom back bar button

}

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Two thoughts - first, you could subclass vA. vASubclass creates its custom back button and calls -dismissViewController.  (super) vA is what you push on the stack.

OR, in vB's -prepareForSegue, examine the segue identifier, and if modal add the custom button to vA there, and setup the target-action to call -dismissViewController from within vB.

Comment: Used second approach, ll try 1st one next time and update.